# R output likert results

Tags: r

I'm using *likert* package to deal with data in likert scales. But I don't know how to output the likert table in a csv file.

```
library(likert)
a<- rep(1:5, 10)
b<- rep(1:5, 10)
a<- factor(a)
b<- factor(b)
c<- data.frame(a, b)
scaledc<- likert(c)
write.table(aggScaled, file="~/DATA/scaledc.csv")
```

It gave an error message:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""likert"" to a data.frame
```

Comment: Try `write.table(scaledc$results, file="~/DATA/scaledc.csv")` (not sure where `aggScaled` came from in this example.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the mistake. Unfortunately, this didn't work. The results can be written in the file but values are not delimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MrFlick I found the correct answer. The command should be:

```
write.table(scaledc$results, file="~/DATA/scaledc.csv", sep = ",", row.names = F)
```